# Can a contract know the creation date of accounts?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts

Is the creation date of accounts part of consensus? Can I query it within contracts? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creationdate of an account is not stored in the chainbase. Accountnames are primarily stored in the user_resources_table which only contains accountname and resources. There's no extra table which stores accountname/creationdate-pairs so there's no way to query the creationdate of an account on-chain.

see here: [eosio.system](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.system)